# how to receive regex from command line in python

Tags: python, regex, command-line-arguments

I want to receive a delimiter like '\t' (tab) from command line,
and use it to parse a text file.

If I put

```
delimiter = sys.argv[1]
```

in the code, and type from the command line

```
$ python mycode.py "\t"
```

delimiter is `'\\t'` i.e., python does its thing to preserve input string as is.

I want to convert this to '\t' so that I can use e.g.,

```
'a\tb\tc'.split(delimiter)
```

to get `['a','b','c']`.

I've tried to convert '\' to '\', but failed.

Is there a built-in python function to handle regex from the command line?

Comment: why not use [re.split()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2 you can use `str.decode('string_escape')`:

```
>>> '\\t'.decode('string_escape')
'\t'
```

In Python 3 you have to encode the string to bytes first and then use `unicode_escape`:

```
>>> '\\t'.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
'\t'
```

Both solutions accept any escape sequence and will decode them correctly, so you could even use some fancy unicode stuff:

```
>>> '\\t\\n\\u2665'.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
'\t\n♥'
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution to my problem. I see I was searching the wrong keyword. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

It's not really regexp you're looking for, it's escape sequences.

You *could* use `eval`, as long as you're perfectly aware of the terrible security consequences, or roll your own string replacement/regexp based escape sequence unescaper.

(Who knows, maybe `arg = arg.replace("\\t", "\t")` is enough for you?)

As a workaround you could do

```
$ python mycode.py `echo -ne '\t'`
```

to (ab) use the Unix echo command to do the unescaping for you.